# Dos command to move all files from all subdir to one folder

Tags: batch-file, dos

i want to write 2 batch files.

### 1st:

move all files in subdirs to root dir.
eg:

```
Folder1
|_folder2
|___files.jpg
|_folder3
|___files.jpg
```

i want to move all files in folders of folder1 to folder1

---

2nd batch file is
eg:

```
Folder1
|_folder2
|___JPEG
|_____files.jpg
|_folder3
|___JPEG
|_____files.jpg
```

Need to  Delete all files in sub dir then move files from JPEG one level up -to folder2 for example- and rename it to thumbnail.png for example.

i tryed

```
for /r %%f in (*) do ren "%%f" thumbnail.jpg
```

to rename all files but dont know how to delete all files in same folder that containe jpeg folder and how to move files one level up.

Thankx :D hope its not vey complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to your first question, as I understand it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set root=Folder1
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /ad /b /s %root%') do @move "%%f\*.*" %root%
endlocal
```

As I've written it all files at any level are moved. If you only want first level subdirectory files moved, then get rid of the /s.

For your second problem, try a similar approach, but with

```
dir /a-d /b
```

to list all the entries that aren't sub-directories (ie, skip JPEG). This will let you construct the *for* statement that does the deletion, then do another statement that does the move and rename.

You might want to look at calling a sub-routine to do the move, rename, delete. You could then manipulate the filename to change the name. I'm a bit confused about exactly what you want to do in the second case. Also have a look a the help on the *set* and *call* commands if your not sure about extracting the filename and other string manipulations.

If you add comments or edit your question to show exactly what you want then I'm happy to help further.